# allure-results not getting in for specflow on .netcore project

Tags: .net, specflow, allure

Want to generate allure report on my spec flow which is with .net core project.

Have installed
specflow.allure 3.0.0.10

In allureConfig.json mentioned
"directory": "..\allure-results",

After executing the tests not getting allure-results folder.

1. in spec flow steps if anything related to allure should be mentioned?
2. If allureConfig.json should have some other parameters configured for getting allure-results folder

Thanks
winadi